# How to write a polymorphic input function in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, input, polymorphism

I'm trying to write some convenience functions in Scala for reading in arrays of values.

I started with a function that converts a string like "1 1 2 3 5 8" to an Array[Int]:

```
def readInts(in: String) = in.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

This works fine, except that if I want to read not just Ints but Longs or BigInts or Doubles, I need to define a function for each one, which seems wasteful (especially if I generalize to reading in matrices or other compound data)

I'd like to be able to write a single polymorphic function as follows:

```
def readArray[A](in: String) = in.split(" ").map(_.to[A])
```

As far as I understand, this is impossible because the String class doesn't have a polymorphic 'to' method. Alright; I'll try to define it as a helper method instead:

```
def to[A](in: String) = ???
```

It seems like I need to define the method conditionally on the type parameter - if A is Int, then call `in.toInt`; if A is Double, call `in.toDouble`; if A is Tuple2[Int,Int], call a helper method `toTupleOfInts(in)`. As far as I know, this is also impossible.

In the other functional language I know, Haskell, this problem is handled by the 'Read' typeclass, which defines a polymorphic function 'read' that converts from a String to the desired data type.

What is an idiomatic way to do this (i.e. write polymorphic input functions) in Scala?

Comment: you should use parsing combinators. I have not yet mastered them, you may do it yourself or wait for a complete answer

Comment: You say that Haskell's read 'converts from each data type to a String' -- I think you mean that read converts from a String to a desired type?

Comment: @overthink - yeah, that's what I meant. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something very close to Haskell typeclasses. However, it cannot be derived automatically (at least yet, maybe macro will allow that in some future version)

First, define a trait, equivalent to the typeclass.

```
trait Read[A] {
  def read(in: String): A
}
```

Then make some instance implicitly available, preferably in the companion object

```
object Read {

  implicit object ReadInt extends Read[Int] {
    def read(in: String): Int = in.toInt
  }

  implicit object ReadDouble ....

  implicit def readArray[A](implicit readItem: Read[A]) : Read[Array[A]]
    = new Read[Array[A]] {
      def read(in: String) = in.split(" ").map(readItem.read _)
    }

   implicit def readTuple[A,B](implicit readA: Read[A], readB: Read[B]) ...

}
```

Finally, define a method that makes the `Read` easily accessible

```
def read[A](in: String[A])(implicit reader: Read[A]) = reader.read(in)
```

You may call read on any type for which there is a Read instance in implicit scope.